Text AREA not showing up in GUI (2021x r2, Cameo) when running simulation (no issue with text FIELD)
Morning, (2021x r2)
I am using a Text AREA because I need multiple lines of text for clarity. In the GUI that
displays some key value properties
In the containment tree the text area is associated correctly, BUT,
When I run the sim, the text AREA does not display, I am having no issues with text fields,
Searched user manual and you tube for a solution, but no luck.
Hoping there is a Joe Mistake or other something simple going on.
Thank you for any feedback.
I verified in the containment tree that the TextArea was associated with the Group Box in the GUI where I  needed the information to appear.
